# How to get the maximal values and the related coordinates?

Tags: matlab, function

If I have a multihump-function, how can I get the local maximal values and the related coordinates in Matlab?

For example, assume we have

```
x=(-2*pi-0.5:0.1:2*pi+0.5); y=sin(x); plot(x,y);
```

Then we have two local maxima with value 1, namely at positions pi/2 and 1.5 pi/2.

Is there any possibility to let Matlab give me the positions of the maxima and the value, i.e. 1?

What, if we have an example, where we have for instance three local maxima with three different values? Is it possible to let Matlab give me the three positions and the values at this positions?

Comment: The solutions depend highly on the nature of your data, what you know about it, and the toolboxes at your disposal. Are your functions periodic? Are the peaks approximately the same height? One solution in to do `fzero` on the derivative of the data at known intervals.

Comment: Let us assume that the peaks are approximately of the same height but the function is not periodic.

Comment: I was writing my solution while this closed, but here is the short version: (1) [`findpeaks`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) would it for you. (2) Alternativly you sort the array and extract the as many as you like 'largest'.

Comment: @mpaskov 1) It requires the **Signal Processing Toolbox**, not everybody has access to it. 2) if the peaks are not the same size, choosing an arbitrary amount of largest values might just give you one of the maxima, and not all the local maxima in the data. For this, good old derivatives should do the trick.

Comment: You did mention that they were approximately the same high, that is why i though (2) could wok. Maybe you can find the answer in the duplicate question or you can start thinking about a solution of 'manual-`findpeaks`', namely look at adjacent values and if they are all smaller this is 'peak'.